# linq creates new anonymous object; how to declare return type

Tags: c#, linq, return-type, anonymous

The details of the linq expression are not important except for the fact that it creates a new unnamed object:

```
 select new { ... }
```

Thus I have no return type for the function.  There has to be a generic untyped type like Javascript's "any".

```
   public ??? Get(int id)
    {
        var hisGrade = (from p in ctx.Students
                        where p.StudentID == id
                        select new { area = p.Grade.Section, name = p.Grade.GradeName }).FirstOrDefault();
        return hisGrade;
    }
```

Every example I find just shows the code without the enclosing function!

Thanks for your help.
Chuck

Answer (score 1):

You can return `dynamic`, it will declare a type in run-time with two properties: `area` and `name`:

```
   public dynamic Get(int id)
    {
        var hisGrade = (from p in ctx.Students
                        where p.StudentID == id
                        select new { area = p.Grade.Section, name = p.Grade.GradeName }).FirstOrDefault();
        return hisGrade;
    }
```

Thus you can access the members of the object returned, but you will miss the IntelliSense and the type-checking at compile-time:

```
var name = Get(1).name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you assuming it would always have to be an anonymous type that is returned by a Select call? You would be wrong.

```
public struct MyType
{
    public string Area { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Class1
{
    public MyType Get(int id)
    {
        var hisGrade = (from p in ctx.Students
                        where p.StudentID == id
                        select new MyType{ Area = p.Grade.Section, Name = p.Grade.GradeName }).FirstOrDefault();
        return hisGrade;
    }
}
```